# Update label text after dismissing popover in swift

Tags: ios, swift, popover

please help me to update view controller or call a view controller method after dismissing popover.

Comment: Is didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called and the delegate method you implemented in view controller is called?

Comment: No delegate method implemented in view controller is NOT called

Comment: I think you forgot to set `var delegate: DismissGenderPopoverDelegate?` delegate, something like `delegate.delegate = self` in `ViewDidLoad` or `ViewWillAppear`

Comment: In Which Class createProfilePage or in GenderPopoverController ?

Comment: Create  the popoverPresentationViewController in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear itself and set the delegate to self so that the delegate method will be called properly

Comment: unable to set delegate to self please tell me How?

Comment: Thank U Guys Its Working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using Protocol
Created Protocol and called method of that protocol in the class Where I want data from that Popover.